# Is $\Bbb{Q}_p/\Bbb{Z}_p$ isomorphic to $\Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}$ as aan abelian group?

Tags: abelian-groups, p-adic-number-theory

Is $\Bbb{Q}_p/\Bbb{Z}_p$ isomorphic to $\Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}$ as a group ?

My try: I know $\Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}\cong \bigoplus_p:prime　\Bbb{Q}_p/\Bbb{Z}_p$ as group.

If I could prove $\bigoplus_p:prime　\Bbb{Q}_p/\Bbb{Z}_p\cong \Bbb{Q}_p/\Bbb{Z}_p$, the proof ends but this maybe circular arguing.

Comment: Both are torsion groups, so you might try comparing orders. $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ has an element of every order. What can you say about the order of an element of $\mathbb{Q}_{p}/\mathbb{Z}_{p}$?

Comment: The former injects into the latter, so the latter also has an element of every order. This means both are isomorphic abelian group, is this correct ?

Comment: No, it is not. Why do you think $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ injects into $\mathbb{Q}_{p}/\mathbb{Z}_{p}$? (Also, your argument would not make sense even if it did.) I recommend spending a bit of time trying to understand the decomposition of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ you give in your second sentence - it may help you understand how to use my hint. (Of course, you're not obliged to follow my approach.)

Comment: There is a surjective homomorphism $\Bbb{Q/Z\to Q_p/Z_p}$ but the image is $\Bbb{Q/(Q \cap Z_p)}$

Comment: @Alex Wertheim. The decomposition in my second sentence is ''decomposition int o p-primary part'', here p-primary part means the set of all elements of p-th power order. So the latter group does not have for example, order $p-1$ element. Thus two groups are not isomorphic as abelian groups, I think. Is this correct ?

Comment: For every element $a$ in the quotient, there is an $n\geq 0 $ such that $p^na=0.$ That isn't true for $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z.$

Comment: What does your $\oplus$ notation mean?

Comment: Why would $\bigoplus_q A_q \cong A_p$ be even remotely likely to be true? (Don't reuse the variable $p$ in $\bigoplus_p$ like that. There is one value $p,$ and infinitely many terms in the $\bigoplus_q.$)

Comment: @Thomas Andrews. 'in the quotient' means $\Bbb{Q}_p/\Bbb{Z}_p$ ? And why isn't that(for some $n$, $p^na=0$) true in $\Bbb{Q}_p/\Bbb{Z}_p$?

Comment: It is true in $\mathbb Q_p/\mathbb Z_p,$ it is not in $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z.$ Hint: Let $q\neq p$ be another prime, and consider $\frac1q.$